# Unity + SignalR

Tags: c#, unity3d, asp.net, signalr

Начал разрабатывать один проект на Unity. Серверную часть пишу на ASP.NET. Решил использовать SignalR для мультиплеера.

Столкнулся с проблемой:
Дело в том, что я скачал библиотеки SignalR.Client.dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll. Пробовал также устанавливать их с NUGet.
Закинул библиотеки в папку Plugins (в Unity), но не компилируется. Выдаёт исключение:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

Я так понял, он не может прочесть все классы и скомпилировать. Поначалу ошибки были в том, что версии .NET библиотек не соответствовали с версией .NET проекта. Я переставил на 4.0. Ошибка исчезла. Теперь появилась эта.

В WPF и прочих фреймворках SignalR Client работает нормально.
Решил посмотреть один видеоурок. У того всё работает нормально. Говорит, что вам нужно скачать эти библиотеки, но откуда, не сказал (SignalR.Client.dll и Newtonsoft.Json.dll).

Есть ещё вариант - перейти на Node.Js. Но корректно ли использовать 2 сервера одновременно? Один на ASP.NET для БД, второй на Node.JS для мультиплеера?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Я скачал проект Visual Studio по ссылке: [URL="https://github.com/NVentimiglia/SignalR-Unity3d"]https://github.com/NVentimiglia/SignalR-Unity3d[/URL]. Собрал DLL. И закинул в папку Unity/Plugins.